# how to push data from kafka cluster east[KCL _1] to kafka cluster north and if KCL_1 fails switch to kafka cluster west[KCL_2] using MirrorMaker2

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

Scenario:
Two Data centers *East DC(data center)* and *West DC* both have same data stream and serve as backup of each other. 
*North DC* needs continuous data either from East or West DC.

During my search some names show up like MirrorMaker2, U replicator & custom build Kakfa connect.

I thought of using *MirrorMaker2(MM2)* for this purpose, initially data will be pushed from *East DC* and suppose if *East DC* fails at 11:00 AM then *MM2* will switch to *West DC* and push data 11:00 AM onwards.

Designing such solution for the first time so just want to confirm about my direction of using MM2 or alternate. 
Any suggestions/sharing past experience can help, Thanks

Comment: 1) how would they have "same data stream" if the consumer offsets are **unique** to each cluster?

Answer (score 0):

If your east cluster fails, then no data will be pushed to west (or north) from *any* mirroring solution.

Not clear what you mean by "switch". Any client configured to use east cluster will stop working in this case, because they don't know anything about west, or north (kafka clients can only be configured to one cluster at a time). Mirroring solutions aren't associated with external client configurations / service discovery.

And if they were updated to west (with downtime) and east cluster came back online, then you need downtime again to switch them back to east. **But**, probably shouldn't do that until west-east mirroring has completed. After which case, I'm not entirely sure how any "updated east consumer" knows what data has already been processed from the west cluster. You'd need some other centralized, external data store tracking record ids / metadat, at the very least.

---

If producers only exist individually in east and west, and consumers only in north, then that's a "fan in" kafka pattern, and you will need to be mindful of significant consumer load if the east/west clusters / mirrors restart.

---

For these reasons, I find Kafka cluster mirroring isn't bullet proof solution for active-active replication.
I suppose this is why people lean towards Apache Pulsar or Confluent "Cluster Linking" solutions.

Comment: My plan for the solution involves serving all consumers from the North. To achieve this, either the East DC or the West DC will be utilized to transfer data to the North.  ................

The topics and records will be identical between the East and West regions. In case the current solutions are insufficient, I intend to develop a customized replicator that will automatically switch from the primary to the failover data center (East to West) starting from the next record.

Comment: You cannot guarantee data will be the same on east and west, though. What if producers have exceptions while sending to one region, but not the other? Then you'll have mismatch. As mentioned, automatic failover is already a feature in other solutions. Then you don't need to spend your time working on your own customized logic